# Dealership does not want to give me the loan contract agreement and maintenance package detail signed?

Tags: consumer-protection, breach-of-contract

I purchased my car on April 17,2020, after signing paperwork and waiting 2 hours for the car to be ready to go, I expected my contract agreement and my maintenance package details to be printed and emailed to me as requested. I've called numerous times and when to the dealership and when ever I go there is no one to help me when I get there. I went to get an oil and filter change for my vehicle, and i ended up having to pay for everything out of pocket when i was informed by dealer that maintenance was included in the deal. I was also informed that my payments for my vehicle was $750 monthly, and when I went to make my first payment it stated 850 monthly. I was given $2000 to help with first 7 months car payments, then I can return and refinance. I was told to put up $500 and $250 from the 2000 dollars given to help with monthly payments. I need some help figuring out what to do next.

Comment: Do you know what the paperwork you signed says?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i dont remember verbatim what the contract stated, But i remember most of what was said to me, and i have friend with me when i was signing everything. @DavidSchwartz

Comment: How do I solved the issue with getting the contract agreement signed from the merchant. and how do i deal with the maintenance package that was added to my contract that was added to my contract agreement?@IñakiViggers

Comment: The next thing to do is contact a lawyer.

Comment: Thank you @Mark

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that your question was that what you should do now!

You need to send a legal notice to the dealer to provide you with a photocopy or scanned copy of your signed agreement. It is an act of tort not to give you a copy, as discussed earlier with you. After you get the contract, check with a lawyer or by yourself if you've been duped.